# Exchange 2003 mailbox migrated to 2010 not showing up in Address book

Tags: email, exchange-2010

I have migrated about 45 mailboxes at this point from our single instance of Exchange 2003 to a High Availability Exchange 2010 environment successfully. However one mailbox moved successfully and the user is able to send and receive e-mail internally and externally with no problems but they do not show up in the Global Address List. The OAB is owned by an Exchange 2010 mailbox server. What am I missing?

- Did they appear in the GAL without issues when their mailbox was on Exchange 2003?
    yes
- Was it OK when the OAB generation server was Exchange 2003?
    Yes
- Does rebuilding the OAB help?
    I did an update to the OAB and it didn't change anything
- Are there any OAB errors in the event log?
    I do not see any errors in the even logs

One interesting thing is that in an e-mail message if I select All Users from the All Address list the user shows up there but not in the Global Address List.

Answer (score 0):

If you could edit your question to include the following, it might aid the troubleshooting.

- Did they appear in the GAL without issues when their mailbox was on Exchange 2003?
- Was it OK when the OAB generation server was Exchange 2003?
- Does rebuilding the OAB help?
- Are there any OAB errors in the event log?

I assume you have verified the **Hide user from Exchange address lists** is not ticked in the Exchange Management Console?

Is the user an administrative user (or have they ever been)? Check out [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/202605/offline-address-book-not-updating-for-1-user-after-adding-exchange-2010-to-our-en) which had me tearing my hair out for the best part of a morning. From what you describe, the symptoms sound similar enough for that to be a possible explanation.

Comment: Added your edits to my post

Comment: @TJ Cool, thanks. Is the **adminCount** property of the Active Directory user account set (as per the linked question)?